# Is there a way I can use a user's input in a WHERE clause in triggers? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to prevent insertion if the conditions are not met. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER flightBookingLimit 
ON Booking_Ticket
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(
SELECT COUNT(Booking_Details.Booking_ID), Passenger_Details.Name, Booking_Details.Flight_No
FROM Booking_Ticket
LEFT JOIN Booking_Details ON Booking_Ticket.Booking_ID = Booking_Details.Booking_ID
LEFT JOIN Passenger_Details ON Booking_Details.Passenger_ID = Passenger_Details.Passenger_ID
LEFT JOIN Flight_Schedule ON Booking_Details.Flight_No = Flight_Schedule.Flight_No
LEFT JOIN Aircraft ON Flight_Schedule.AircraftID = Aircraft.AircraftID
LEFT JOIN Airline ON Aircraft.AirlineID = Airline.AirlineID
WHERE Airline.AirlineName = 'Emirates Airlines'
GROUP BY Passenger_Details.Name, Booking_Details.Flight_No
HAVING COUNT(Booking_Details.Booking_ID) >= 4
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'This flight only allows a maximum of 4 bookings' 
END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Booking_Ticket 
    SELECT Booking_ID,Passenger_ID,Flight_No,Reservation_Status,Special_ServiceID,Flight_MealsID,Flight_TripsID,Flight_ClassesID,Ticket_Status,Basic_Fare,Total_Fare
    FROM inserted
END
```

In the WHERE clause, I would like to do something like:

```
WHERE Airline.AirlineName = 'Emirates Airlines' AND Passenger_Details.Name = 'Michael Stuart' AND Booking_Details.Flight_No = 'MH101'
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the user's input when performing insertion queries? Hardcoding these clauses does not help me do what I want to achieve.

Comment: Print? Nope - do not try to "communicate" with a person via a trigger. You throw an error and let the caller handle it. You should not use print or attempt to return a resultset from a trigger. In addition, you assume that a single row is inserted (despite the attempt to handle multiple rows) based on the text of your message. That is not a valid assumption. Lastly, your EXISTS usage needs to refer to the inserted virtual table somehow - otherwise it is checking every ticket that exists in your database and not just the newly inserted ones.

Comment: `<terrible_idea>` You can use [`Session_Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to pass additional data to a trigger. What if it isn't set before the trigger fires? What if it isn't reset and contains stale data when the trigger fires? Executive summary: Don't do this. `</terrible_idea>`

Answer (score 1):

No, not on 2 levels.

- One, a WHERE clause in general allows no user interaction. SQL is not having, generally, ANY user interaction.
- Triggers are FULLY reactive. There is zero way to inject anything that is not in a different table (you COULD have settings in a table). This is just how they are done.

Generally the UI of the application layer puts together the SQL as you want it.